# Syntax of "Он как подорвался всё жрать"

Tags: значения, идиомы

I read this in a [story](https://pikabu.ru/story/kogda_ochen_khochesh_domoy_6531031) online:

> Вечером сестра пришла забирать, а пацан на полу лежит сытый и даже
>   конструктор собирать не хочет. Я говорю: "Таня, а чё ты ему сказала
>   такого? Он как подорвался всё жрать.

According to the context, I can only conclude that this means that the kid ate so much that he almost burst, but grammatically I can't reconcile that meaning with the actual Russian words/grammar. Is there an idiom here at play that I don't know about?

Comment: and may i ask for your English native speaker opinion on [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/487982/superlative-or-not)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`как`** + perfective verb in the past/future tense or imperative means a sudden start and intensity of an act all in the past tense, e.g.

**`он как закричал/закричит/закричи`** ≈ `he just suddenly yelled so hard`

**`подорвался`** is slang for **`вскочил`**, **`резко принялся`**, **`пустился`**, **`бросился`**

So the meaning of the phrase in the quotation is as follows

> What is that that you told him? (Because) He just suddenly started devouring everything = Внезапно принялся всё пожирать

Comment: Great answer! So it's like "What did you say to him? All of a sudden he up and started eating everything in sight!" Got it!)))

Comment: @CocoPop yup...

Comment:  I hope somebody didn't tell you that "yup" in any way means "you're welcome"

Comment: @CocoPop they hadn't, but it was in confirmation of your reading of the sentence, not in acknowledgment of accolade

Comment:  Good to know!

Comment: @CocoPop just to double check, is something wrong with 'yup'? connotations i'm missing?

Comment: To me personally, there's a difference between YEP and YUP. The former, is a more emphatic, enthusiastic, "quick" form of YES. For instance, you agree with something so readily that you answer "yes" a little faster and snappier than usual. For instance, if you had responded YEP(!) above, it would signify "That's it! You got it!" But YUP is like the most disinterested, emotionless "yes" you can muster. It's like saying the absolute least when you don't really want to say anything at all.

Comment: I imagine a moody teenager or a grumpy senior who don't really like to talk to people and when they're forced to answer a question in the affirmative, they give you an offhanded "yup..." 

Comment: @CocoPop OK, interesting, at any rate that's not how i meant it, and a cursory online check hadn't revealed such connotations, so i took it to be synonymous to yep if not still more informal... Russian approximate parallel to what you've described would be **угу** (used in a writing as well) or **мугу** (only used in speech, haven't encountered it in writing), same interjection as the English uh-huh, and the difference between your **yep** and **yup** could be likened to that between **ага** and **угу**

Comment: I didn't think that's how you meant it. It's kind of a cultural-linguistic thing - as in Russian, I'm sure. You see someone use something and figure "why not?" I just wanted to make sure you knew how it comes across. When I read it, I interpreted it as "yeah, whatever, I'm off to answer another post..." hahahahaha Thank you for explaining the Russian equivalents - it's been a very illuminating discussion!

Comment: AND the ellipsis after the "yup" didn't help 

Comment: One more observation: the form YUP comes from the need to say YES with as little movement and energy in the mouth as possible - in some cases, you don't even hear the initial [y]. That tells you everything)))